# Biased MLE estimate of mean (expectation)

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference, parameter-estimation

Please give an example of p.m.f. or p.d.f. , the maximum likely-hood estimate of whose mean (expectation) is a biased estimator . Thanks

Comment: Got something from an answer below?

Answer (score 3):

One of the most classical examples might be the following: assume that $(X_i)_{1\leqslant i\leqslant n}$ is i.i.d. exponential with parameter $\lambda$, then the likelihood is $$\ell(x_1,\ldots,x_n)=\lambda^n\mathrm e^{-\lambda(x_1+\cdots+x_n)},$$ hence the MLE for $\lambda$ is $$\hat\lambda=\frac{n}{X_1+\cdots+X_n}.$$ For every $i$, $E(X_i)=1/\lambda$, hence, by convexity, $$E(\hat\lambda)\gt\frac{n}{E(X_1)+\cdots+E(X_n)}=\lambda.$$ An explicit computation yields, for every $n\geqslant2$, $$E(\hat\lambda)=\frac{n}{n-1}\lambda.$$

Comment: Could you please give a proof $E(\hat\lambda)=\frac{n}{n-1}\lambda$

Comment: It is direct once one writes down the PDF of $X_1+\cdots+X_n$. Can you do this?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** consider $$f_u(x) = \begin{cases}
\frac 1u & \text{ if } 0< x < u \\
0 & \text{ otherwise. }
\end{cases}
$$

$$
\hat u_{ml} = \max X_k
\\
\max X_k < u \implies Eu_{ml} < u 
$$

**formal proof:**
$$
E\hat u_{ml} = \int_0^u P(\max X_k > x) dx
=  \int_0^u [1- P(\max X_k \le x)] dx
\\
=  \int_0^u [1- P(X \le x)^n] dx
= u - u \int_0^u \left(\frac xu
\right)^n \frac{dx}u
= u\left( 1-\frac 1{n+1}
\right) < u
$$